# AjaxControlToolkit requires ASP.NET Ajax 4.0 scripts

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Can anyone have a solution for this issue

Microsoft JScript runtime error: AjaxControlToolkit requires ASP.NET Ajax 4.0 scripts. Ensure the correct version of the scripts are referenced. If you are using an ASP.NET ScriptManager, switch to the ToolkitScriptManager in AjaxControlToolkit.dll.

I am using asp.net 3.5, VS 2008. The version i can see in the AjaxControlToolKit.dll file 3.5.40412.2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check if this link helps you resolve your issue -

http://blog.thinkoriginally.com/2010/05/03/microsoft-jscript-runtime-error-ajaxcontroltoolkit-requires-asp-net-ajax-4-0-scripts/

EDIT: Check this link for dll load error resolution -

http://geekswithblogs.net/LessonsLearned/archive/2008/08/21/hidden-surprises-in-.net-3.5-service-pack-1.aspx

Comment: i have gone through this link. when i change the scriptmanager to toolcriptmanager it is showing this error       "Could not load type 'System.Web.UI.ScriptReferenceBase' from assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'"

Comment: @saknet - Check my edited answer for your type load error resolution.

Comment: Did not work for me.  The answer below, from @Spidy, did work.

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

Change

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

to

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="toolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

Answer (score 6):

Try deleting `Microsoft.ScriptManager.MSAjax.dll` in the bin folder..

Comment: Never follow-up on people who suggest to delete things on your hard drive. A better suggestion would've been to rename it or relocate it.

Comment: Okay.. advice noted! Thank you

Comment: In addition to renaming Microsoft.ScriptManager.MSAjax.dll in the bin folder, make sure it's not in the References section of your Visual Studio project. I never added it, but it ended up there anyway and bedeviled me for days until I realized it was there.

Answer (score 1):

For others hitting this problem: if you have assemblies in your bin directory that cannot be loaded, even if you do not reference them in your project, `GetAjaxFrameworkAssemblyAttribute` will throw an exception the first time it is loaded, then fail to work (without throwing an exception) on future loads.  This issue may only happen sporadically.  See [Microsoft Connect Issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/588777/custom-attribute-load-failure-in-getajaxframeworkassemblyattribute) and [Google Groups issue/work-around discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/websync/browse_thread/thread/83c1f88abbb00b80?pli=1) .  So, try not to stuff unusable DLLs in your bin directory.

Answer (score 1):

I Think you have problem with your VS 2008 version. Because Ajax 3.5 dll requires minimum *Visual studio service pack 1*. But you may not have service pack 1. so please install it.

Before installing service pack 1 remove Ajax toolkit from toolbar and when installation complete again add it and run. I was also having the same problem and I have solved in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Delete Microsoft.ScriptManager.MSAjax.dll and Microsoft.ScriptManager.WebForms.dll from your bin folder. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use AjaxControlToolkit.dll & register it by

`<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>`

& then instead of script manager use

`<cc1:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server"></cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when I had a ScriptManager set up on my master page that was added as part of the default template.

The content page I was getting the error on had a ToolKitScriptManager and the master page had the ScriptManager.

I removed the ScriptManager from the master page to get rid of the error.

Here's a reference page detailing the differences between the 2.
http://blog.turlov.com/2008/05/scriptmanager-vs-toolkitscriptmanager.html

Hope that helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

after searching and trying many solutions, this works for me:

in projectName.csproj file, delete `<Folder Include="bin\" />` in `<ItemGroup>`

my situation:

1. I don't have `Microsoft.ScriptManager.MSAjax.dll` in the bin folder.
2. changing `<asp:ScriptManager ...>` to `<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ...>` makes no sense, because there are too many tags to change