# Upgrade from Web Site to Web Application changed how scripts are loaded

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, asp.net-4.5

**Error**

After the upgrade I am recieving the error

> AjaxControlToolkit requires ASP.NET Ajax 4.0 scripts. Ensure the
>   correct version of the scripts are referenced. If you are using an
>   ASP.NET ScriptManager, switch to the ToolkitScriptManager in
>   AjaxControlToolkit.dll.

**What did I do?**

I have converted a Web Site to a Web Application (Original site was running as ASP.NET 4.5)

To perform the conversion I did the following steps

- Created a new web application
- Removed everything from it
- Added all the references that the current site uses
- Copied the current site into the new project folder
- Included all relevent site files (aspx, js etc)
- Ran the Convert to Web Application function

This all ran through fine and the site worked other than needing to remove the default project namespace (Original site is in VB.NET)

Now I am getting a problem with the Ajax Toolkit I checked where scripts are loading from and they are pointing at

> /Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjax.js

Before conversion they loaded from

> /ScriptResource.axd?d=x6wALODbMJK5e0eRC_p1LbQ8N_ZndRAt5q6HCL5aSqX5zUL0WP6Os-UOD4fm_CxLYX2ipe5ZSsH6CuSPYIwCxFyqOqfAKX-tAVDEc-jO142vEjkpSAWNccmIg7QpwH-q0&t=7c776dc1

**What have I Tried?**

Upgraded to the latest version of the AjaxToolkit (April release for .NET 4.5)

I noticed the template website puts the scripts in the scripts folder then bundles them.  I added all this functionality to the site but the toolkit doesn't like this version of the scripts.

I noticed the script manage mention about using ToolkitScriptManager instead of ScriptManager so all instances of ScriptManager have been replaced.

I have tried removing the scripts folder to see if that was interfering but that causes an error saying the "ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load." (To be honest I was expecting this but ran out of ideas)

Compared the template web.config with the current sites nothing seemed relevant to move over or already existed.

**Question?**

Where have I gone wrong in the conversion or is something extra needed to enable the AjaxToolkit?

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: opps added it to the top :)

Comment: Perhaps this item will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862280/ajaxcontroltoolkit-requires-asp-net-ajax-4-0-scripts

Comment: I have already tried swapping the ScriptManager to ToolkitScriptManager.  Also I forgot to note above I used the 4.5 version of the toolkit